# Why can't I move some of the objects in this model?

Tags: python, transforms, properties

I recently downloaded [this model of a car](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/69075). This model consists of several objects. For some of the objects (such as "Neumatico"), I can change the location of the object using the Python Console with

```py
bpy.data.objects['Neumatico'].location = [0,0,-1]
```

or in the Properties Editor via

*Properties -> Object -> Transform -> Location*

Both methods successfully move the object in the 3D View. However, for other objects (such as "Detalles 1" in the model), neither the Python nor Properties techniques above move the object. Although both techniques do change the location values, the objects do not move in the 3D view. Also, the behavior I described for location also occurs for rotation.

I also tried using the command `bpy.context.scene.update()` but that didn't seem to help.

Why can I move some parts of the model, but not others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior occurred because some of the objects in the model had been added as rigid bodies. I made the objects movable again by going to

*Properties -> Physics*

and clicking the button to remove the rigid body settings from the object.